# TypeScript: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type typeof css file has no index signature

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Im converting React app to use Typescript. And Im getting the following error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Services/Services.tsx:34:29
    TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof "/Users/path/to/project/src/components/Services/Services.css"' has no index signature.
```

Webpack config

```
    const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    entry: ["./index.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "www"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: "sourcemap", // has to be removed in production
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
        modules: [path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.(jsx?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"]
            },
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                            // namedExport: true
                        }
                    },
                    "postcss-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            outputPath: "images/"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And this is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./www/", 
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true, 
        "module": "es6", 
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react", 
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

This is the Services.tsx file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import queryString from "query-string";

import * as styles from "./Services.css";
import globalStyles from "../../styles/global.css";
import SubHeader from "../common/SubHeader";

class Services extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles["services"]}>
                <SubHeader text={"MY SERVICES"} />
                <div className={styles["body"]}>
                    //loop over props and render
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
    return {
        services: state.services,
        vehicles: state.vehicles
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Services);
```

This is the Services.css file:

```
.services {
    padding-top: 64px;
    .body {
        margin: 16px;
    }
}
```

And this is the Services.css.d.ts file created by typings-for-css-modules-loader:

```
export interface IServicesCss {
  'services': string;
  'body': string;
}

export const locals: IServicesCss;
```

Im using **typescript: "^2.7.2"** and **typings-for-css-modules-loader: "^1.7.0"**

I cant figure out what the error means. I searched online and all the resource mention about index signature related. Since Im new to Typescript, cant figure out what it takes to fix the issue.

Comment: It would sure help if you showed the Services.tsx file, where the error is being flagged.

Comment: Also share the .css file. It looks like you're using some module that allows you to write CSS as Typescript instead.

Comment: @kshetline Added tsx file. Please have a look.

Comment: @Evert Added css and css.d.ts file. Please have a look.

Comment: `import * as styles from "./Services.css";`  doesn't make sense.

Comment: Add this in webpack.config.js might help :  resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [ ".ts", ".tsx"]
    },

Comment: I think you need keyof if you use styles[“body”]

Comment: @Kokodoko Im not aware of keyof in styles. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you use a string to access an object `obj[‘prop’]` then typescript can’t know rhe type. It will be inferred as `any` but that’s not allowed if you use `noImplicitAny` in tsconfig. Typescript introduced `keyof` to associate string access with the correct type - an `index signature`

Answer (score 1):

Try this might help [article for style loader](https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10)

Typescript is unable to load the css files or is unable to find the declarations for the same please do try these webpack.config.js changes of adding a style-loader in plugins might help and your related problem will be solved

Comment: I have added that already. That loader is the one that is creating the Services.css.d.ts.

But its not helping issue.

Answer (score 0):

**The error/warning was coming because namedExport was not set as true. (I had it commented out)**

Note: even with namedExport: false, the code will run. But the .css.d.ts file created will be of the following structure:

```
export interface IServiceDetailCardCss {
  'service-detail-card': string;
  'left-col': string;
  'amount': string;
  'symbol': string;
}

export const locals: IServiceDetailCardCss;
```

But, if you set namedExport: true, each classname will be an individual named export, like this:

```
export const serviceDetailCard: string;
export const leftCol: string;
export const amount: string;
export const symbol: string;
```

..and you will be able to reference them like styles.serviceDetailCard in your JSX.

Note: If you enable namedExport: true, you should also couple it with camelCase: true, to convert classnames of type some-classname to someClassname.